# Debian/Ubuntu now shows nothing available to autoremove, after a segfault

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, dpkg, segmentation-fault

So as not to obscure the problem with output,

1. I was trying prompted to run `autoremove`
2. I ran it.
3. It segfaulted.
4. After which, nothing shows to be `autoremove`-able.
5. Things are still present which were on the `autoremove` list?

**I'd like to retry `autoremove` again.**

```
# sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  amd64-microcode aspnetcore-store-2.0.0 dotnet-host dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.0 dotnet-runtime-deps-2.1.0-preview2-26406-04 gcc-7-base:i386 gfortran-mingw-w64
  gfortran-mingw-w64-i686 gfortran-mingw-w64-x86-64 gnat-mingw-w64 gnat-mingw-w64-base gnat-mingw-w64-i686 gnat-mingw-w64-x86-64 gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-orca
  gnupg-agent gsettings-ubuntu-schemas gvfs-bin indicator-sound intel-microcode iucode-tool libapparmor-perl libarmadillo7 libbabeltrace-ctf1 libbind9-140
  libboost-date-time1.62.0 libboost-filesystem1.62.0 libboost-filesystem1.62.0:i386 libboost-filesystem1.65.1:i386 libboost-iostreams1.62.0 libboost-system1.62.0
  libboost-system1.62.0:i386 libboost-system1.65.1:i386 libboost-thread1.62.0 libc++1 libc++abi1 libcapnp-0.5.3 libcapnp-0.5.3:i386 libcapnp-0.6.1 libcapnp-0.6.1:i386
  libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcdio13 libcommons-codec-java libcryptsetup4 libdfu1 libdns-export162 libdns162 libegl1-mesa:i386 libfreerdp-cache1.1
  libfreerdp-client1.1 libfreerdp-codec1.1 libfreerdp-common1.1.0 libfreerdp-core1.1 libfreerdp-crypto1.1 libfreerdp-gdi1.1 libfreerdp-locale1.1
  libfreerdp-plugins-standard libfreerdp-primitives1.1 libfreerdp-utils1.1 libfwupd1 libgcr-3-common libgeos-3.5.1 libgnome-desktop-3-12 libgnome-games-support-1-2
  libgsoap-2.8.49 libgtk2-perl libhttpclient-java libhttpcore-java libical2 libicu57:i386 libidn11:i386 libisc-export160 libisc160 libisccc140 libisccfg140
  libiso9660-10 libiso9660-8 libjsoup-java libkeybinder0 liblivemedia58 libllvm5.0:i386 liblouis12 liblouisutdml7 liblttng-ust-ctl2 liblttng-ust-ctl4 liblttng-ust0
  liblwgeom-2.3-0 liblwres141 libmirclient9 libmirclient9:i386 libmircommon7 libmircommon7:i386 libmircore1 libmircore1:i386 libmirprotobuf3 libmirprotobuf3:i386
  libnetcdf11 libntfs-3g872 libopencv-core3.1:i386 libopencv-core3.1 libopencv-imgproc3.1:i386 libopencv-imgproc3.1 liborcus-0.12-0 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring
  libpango-perl libplexus-classworlds2-java libplexus-utils-java libpoppler68 libprotobuf-lite10:i386 libqca2-plugin-ossl libqgis-core2.14.18
  libqgis-networkanalysis2.14.18 libqgispython2.14.18 libqpdf18 libqtwebkit4 libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-gtk2 libruby2.3 libsbsms10 libsodium18 libsodium18:i386
  libsss-nss-idmap0 libsuitesparseconfig4 libtbb2 libtbb2:i386 libtinyxml2-5 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libunistring0 liburcu6 libva-wayland1
  libvcdinfo0 libvpx4 libvpx4:i386 libwagon2-java libwinpr-crt0.1 libwinpr-dsparse0.1 libwinpr-environment0.1 libwinpr-file0.1 libwinpr-handle0.1 libwinpr-heap0.1
  libwinpr-input0.1 libwinpr-interlocked0.1 libwinpr-library0.1 libwinpr-path0.1 libwinpr-pool0.1 libwinpr-registry0.1 libwinpr-rpc0.1 libwinpr-sspi0.1
  libwinpr-synch0.1 libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 libwinpr-thread0.1 libwinpr-utils0.1 libx264-148 libx264-148:i386 libx265-130:i386 libx265-130 libxerces-c3.1 libxfont1
  linux-headers-4.13.0-40 linux-headers-4.13.0-40-generic linux-image-4.13.0-40-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-40-generic python-beautifulsoup python-functools32
  python-imaging ruby2.3 snapd-login-service tcpd xfce4-volumed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 171 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1,177 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg received a segmentation fault.
```

Nothing left to autoremove,

```
# sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Things are still installed (note `linux-image-4.13.0-40-generic` is in the list above and `ii` means installed)

```
$ dpkg -l linux-image-extra-4.13.0-40-generic
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                 Version                 Architecture           
+++-====================================-=======================-=======================
ii  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-40-generic  4.13.0-40.45            amd64
```

They can still be manually, but I'd like to have dpkg to the same `autoremove` reoutine again.

```
# sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-image-4.13.0-40-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.13.0-40-generic* linux-image-extra-4.13.0-40-generic*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 238 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Can I tell Debian to recalculate the `autoremove` list?

This is on a dist-upgrade from Ubuntu 17.10 to Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Do you know why it dpkg segfaulted? Might want to make a proper bug report otherwise, so that it can be fixed

Comment: @gurka Potentially bad memory, but I would hope that at (a) my package manager was transactional, and (b) it could recover from a crash even if it took some work on my part.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a bug in apt, where the `/var/lib/apt/extended_states` for those packages was cleared before dpkg returned success.

You can compare an old entry from `/var/backups/apt.extended_states*` to verify if that is actually the case.

If that's true, you can either:

1. Run `apt-mark auto linux-image-4.13.0-40-generic` for the automatically installed packages which were removed
2. Copy any entries which were removed from `extended_states` from the backup.

As near as I can tell, there aren't any bugs open in [Debian against apt](https://bugs.debian.org/apt) which match this issue.

Comment: When you say removed, you mean removed *from the states* but left in tact on the system, correct?

Comment: Right. My best guess is that the entry was just removed from `extended_states` or the whole file was truncated.

For whatever reason, dpkg segfaulted before it even started removing those packages.

Comment: Bad ass. Didn't know about `apt-mark` this is *exactly* what I wanted. And, I do agree with what happening. What a nasty bug. Hope you stick around at [unix.se]. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it probably hasn't been seen because dpkg very rarely segfaults. If you could, please open a bug against apt with the logs that you show and a diff of the `extended_status` file.

Comment: I just did what you suggested so I don't think I have it any more, and I added and removed stuff since then but I don't think it'll be required. I can confirm your suspension that those entries (which I looked for before I ran `apt-mark` were in fact not in that file).

Comment: Wow! Excellent first answer!  +1